# Dask: longer run time than Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dask

**Edited to make a self contained example**

I am having some issues getting Dask to help speed up my code. I have a dataframe of 9.9M rows X 18 columns that has 2.75 million groupby objects using 
the **tour_id** column in the dataframe. I would like to run a custom function on these groupby objects (which would act like dataframe) in parallel 
and thus using Dask is a good candidate.

The custom function generates two values (start_time and arrival_time) for each row in the group. Other than the first row of each group, these two values 
depend upon the values established in the *preceeding row* and a predefined sampling distribution. Thus, looping through a group seems to be the only option. There could be a way of doing this more efficiently w/o going to Dask and I am all ears to it.

Now for the problem at hand. I am showing a stripped down version of all the dataframes to reproduce the situation.

First, the primary dataframe called temp_df1. The final output from Dask will be concatenated to this data, and it also serves as an input to the
function(s) that Dask calls.

```
import pandas as pd
temp_df1 = pd.DataFrame({'trip_id':[22186702,22186703,22186704,26777219,26777220,26777221,26777222,26777223],
            'tour_id':[13525325,13525325,13525325,13525328,13525328,13525328,13525328,13525328],
            'start_time':[8,0,0,10.92,0,0,0,0],
            'ttime_mins':[3.810553,4.649286,2.917499,5.415158,3.800613,1.829472,1.829472,8.643289],
            'arrival_time':[8.063509,0,0,11.010253,0,0,0,0],
            'weight_column':['HBO_outbound','HBO_outbound','HBO_inbound','HBO_outbound','HBO_outbound','NHB_outbound','NHB_inbound','HBM_inbound']})
```

Second, the time sampling datafame. This dataframe stores all the observed weights stratified by time (hour in the day) and weight_segment (HBO_inbound, HBM_inbound etc). 
The functions (fun4 or fun6) **sample an hour** from this dataframe for each row other than the first row of each group, and segmented by column.

```
time_dist = pd.DataFrame({'Time':[8,9,10,11,12,13,14],
            'HBO_outbound':[1573,419,339,544,600,453,100],
            'HBO_inbound':[1573,419,339,544,100,953,800],
            'HBM_outbound':[1573,419,339,544,640,463,90],
            'HBM_inbound':[1573,419,339,544,320,453,100],
            'WBO_outbound':[1573,419,339,544,600,453,100],
            'WBO_inbound':[1573,419,339,544,450,803,190],
            'NHB_outbound':[1573,419,339,544,901,543,290],
            'NHB_inbound':[1573,419,339,544,863,453,330]})
```

Now the functions. When running the groupby and apply combination in Dask, I am using Function 4.

```
def fun4(df):
    """
    Args: dataframe (temp_df1)
    """
    #### loop through the dataframe supplied
    for i in range(0, df.shape[0]):
        if i == 0:
            start_time = df['start_time'].iloc[i]  ### get the start_time of the first row that is precomputed
            arrival_time = df['arrival_time'].iloc[i]  ### get the arrival_time of the first row that is precomputed
            tour_id = df['tour_id'].iloc[i] ### get the name of the tour being solved
            results_frow.append(start_time)
            results_frow.append(arrival_time)
            results_frow.append(tour_id)
        else:
            tour_id = df['tour_id'].iloc[i] ### get the name of the tour being solved
            arrival_time_prev = results_frow[-2] ### get the arrival time of the previous row as this serves as a constraint
            time_dist1 = time_dist.loc[time_dist['Time'] >= arrival_time_prev] ### slice the time distributions before sampling
            weight_column = df['weight_column'].iloc[i] ### get weight column to sample from

            #### sample a time and calculate a new arrival time as a result
            if len(time_dist1)> 0:
                start_time = time_dist1.sample(n=1, weights= time_dist1[weight_column], replace=True, random_state=prng)
                start_time = start_time[['Time']].values ###
                start_time = start_time[0][0]
            else:
                start_time = results_frow[-2]

            newarrival_time = start_time + df['ttime_mins'].iloc[i]/60 ### caluclate the arrival time by adding start time to the travel time 
            results_frow.append(start_time)
            results_frow.append(newarrival_time)
            results_frow.append(tour_id)

    return  (pd.DataFrame({'start_time': results_frow[0::3],
                              'arrival_time': results_frow[1::3],
                              'tour_id': results_frow[2::3]}))
```

When using map_partitions, I use function 6. The logic is the same for the two lines of groupby code that I thought was needed to make
map_partitions work correctly.

```
def fun6(in_df):
    """
    Args: dataframe (temp_df1)

    """
    results_frow1 = []
    for name, df in in_df.groupby('tour_id'):
        results_frow = []

        for i in range(0, df.shape[0]):

            if i == 0:
                start_time = df['start_time'].iloc[i]  ### get the start_time of the first row that is precomputed
                arrival_time = df['arrival_time'].iloc[i]  ### get the arrival_time of the first row that is precomputed
                tour_id = df['tour_id'].iloc[i] ### get the name of the tour being solved
                results_frow.append(start_time)
                results_frow.append(arrival_time)
                results_frow.append(tour_id)

            else:
                tour_id = df['tour_id'].iloc[i] ### get the name of the tour being solved
                arrival_time_prev = results_frow[-2] ### get the arrival time of the previous row as this serves as a constraint
                time_dist1 = time_dist.loc[time_dist['Time'] >= arrival_time_prev] ### slice the time distributions before sampling
                weight_column = df['weight_column'].iloc[i] ### get weight column to sample from

                # sample a time and calculate a new arrival time as a result
                if len(time_dist1)> 0:
                    start_time = time_dist1.sample(n=1, weights= time_dist1[weight_column], replace=True, random_state=prng)
                    start_time = start_time[['Time']].values ###
                    start_time = start_time[0][0]
                else:
                    start_time = results_frow[-2]

                newarrival_time = start_time + df['ttime_mins'].iloc[i]/60 ### caluclate the arrival time by adding start time to the travel time
                results_frow.append(start_time)
                results_frow.append(newarrival_time)
                results_frow.append(tour_id)

        results_frow1.extend(results_frow)

    return  (pd.DataFrame({'start_time': results_frow1[0::3],
                          'arrival_time': results_frow1[1::3],
                          'tour_id': results_frow1[2::3]}))
```

Now the running and tests.

**Option 1: Using groupby and apply.**

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
results_frow = []
prng = 124

ddf = dd.from_pandas(temp_df1, npartitions=1)
gpb = ddf.groupby('tour_id').apply(fun4, meta = pd.DataFrame(dtype='float64', columns=['start_time', 'arrival_time', 'tour_id'])).compute()
```

Outputs:
WHile the actual values of start_time and arrival_time are correct, the groupby and apply results in more records than what the input had. 
There should only have been 3 records for 13525325 and 5 rows for 13525328. But as seen in the output there are quite a few repeats of 13525325.

```
tour_id     start_time  arrival_time    tour_id

    13525325 8.000000   8.063509    13525325
             9.000000   9.077488    13525325
             10.000000  10.048625   13525325
             8.000000   8.063509    13525325
             9.000000   9.077488    13525325
             10.000000  10.048625   13525325
    13525328 8.000000   8.063509    13525325
             9.000000   9.077488    13525325
             10.000000  10.048625   13525325
             8.000000   8.063509    13525325
             9.000000   9.077488    13525325
             10.000000  10.048625   13525325
             10.920000  11.010253   13525328
             12.000000  12.063344   13525328
             13.000000  13.030491   13525328
             14.000000  14.030491   13525328
             14.030491  14.174546   13525328
```

**Option 2: Using map partitions**

```
import dask.datafame as dd
prng = 124
results_frow = []

temp_df1['hash'] = temp_df1['tour_id'] ### setting a hash to serve as an index for my understanding is that this will be needed to split groups into partitions
temp_df1 = temp_df1.set_index('hash')
ddf = dd.from_pandas(temp_df1, npartitions=1)

gpb = ddf.map_partitions(lambda df:fun6(df), meta = pd.DataFrame(dtype='float64', columns=['start_time', 'arrival_time', 'tour_id'])).compute()
```

Outputs: 
The values and number of records using map_partitions are correct.

```
    start_time  arrival_time  tour_id
0   8.000000    8.063509      13525325
1   9.000000    9.077488      13525325
2   10.000000   10.048625     13525325
3   10.920000   11.010253     13525328
4   12.000000   12.063344     13525328
5   13.000000   13.030491     13525328
6   14.000000   14.030491     13525328
7   14.030491   14.174546     13525328
```

The time results are as follows. I have also added in the pandas version.

```
Rows    Groups  Partitions  Dask - groupby  Dask-partitions Pandas
799     218     1           2.1s            1.59s           1.59s
799     218     2           2.42s           1.8s            -
```

Questions

- Given the problem i.e. wanting to run the custom function in parallel on the 2.75M groups, what must I be using: Groupby/apply or max_partitions?
- Why does Grouby create all the extra rows?
- How can I significantly improve run times using either groupby or max_partitions?

Comment: Oh man, there's no way to tell without knowing what these functions are doing.

Comment: I have added the functions and a summary about what the functions do. Have also added a snapshot of another dataframe that the functions use for sampling. Thx.

Comment: One thing that I must add is that the results gotten from the groupby and apply approach while not wrong with respect to conforming to the logic in the function, actually do create more records than wanted. This does not happen with the map_partitions approach.

Comment: The first thing I'd do is show some verifiable code. This includes all your `import` statements.

Comment: http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2018/02/28/minimal-bug-reports

Comment: I have edited the post to make a working example. Sorry for the long post, but I had to save the functions in here as well as per the initial request.